# Calling Bitkeeper command from telnet

Tags: telnet, bitkeeper

I am calling a perl script in build machine 1 to connect to build machine 2 and call a perl script in build machine 2. The module I am using is Net::Telnet.

Recently I upgraded my bitkeeper in Build machine 2. Since then I am getting the license agreement form of Bitkeeper in the background. So my script is as good as paused till I kill the prompt's process from task manager.

If I kill the process, the bitkeeper clone command will fail and hence my entire build will fail. I am not able to bring this sneaky bkgui.exe process to front and accept the license agreement once and for all.

Can you please help me in solving this problem?

Observations:

1. I am not getting the license error when I open a command prompt in build machine 2 and call the same script which was called from telnet.
2. I ran 'whoami' command in my script running in build machine 2 and found it to be administrator.
3. 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\tlntsvr.exe' is running and the USER is 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
4. When I call telnet from command line of buildmachine 1 and call the script in buildmachine 2, even then the bk command get executed successfully.

I want to run my bitkeeper command in build machine 2 from build machine 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `bk legal -pT` command. See `bk help legal` for usage.

Comment: Detailed Solution: Login to telnet in the same machine. 'telnet localhost' should do that. Run 'bk legal -pT' or 'bk legal -pG' and accept the license. To be on safer side, you can also run 'psexec -i -s cmd' and in the new command window, you can issue the bk legal commands. I followed both the steps and it worked fine.